# JavaScript find longest Uniform Substring

Tags: javascript

Trying to find longest Uniform Substring.

Suppose I have **abbbccda** then it should return **[1, 3]**. Because it starts from index 1 and is 3 characters long.

Other Example:

```
"10000111" =>     [  1, 4  ]
"aabbbbbCdAA" =>  [  2, 5  ]
```

I tried:

```js
function longestUniformSubstring(input){
    
    if(input){
      let arr = input.split("");
      let obj = {};
      
      arr.map((ele, index) => {
        return obj[ele] ? obj[ele][1]++ : obj[ele] = [index,1];
      });
        console.log(obj);  
            
      return obj;
              
    }
    else {
      return [ -1, 0 ];
    }
}

longestUniformSubstring("abbbccda");
```

It gives me object of all character But, no idea how can i get with highest length.

Comment: Side note; that is an inappropriate usage of `map`.  You are not transforming anything and using the result of the map in a variable.  You are simply using it to iterate.  `forEach()` is more appropriate.

Comment: I am getting something in object but, not sure I am right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the string and check the previous character and continue if the caracters are equal.

If not, check the length and assign a new logest array, if necessary and check if a longer string is not possible, then break the loop.

Assign the new found character and set a new start value to the actual index.

```js
function longestUniformSubstring(input) {
    var longest = [-1, 0],
        start = 0,
        character = input[0];

    for (let i = 1; i <= input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i] === character) continue;

        if (longest[1] < i - start) {
            longest = [start, i - start];
            if (i + i - start >= input.length) break;
        }
        character = input[i];
        start = i;
    }
    return longest;
}

console.log(...longestUniformSubstring("aabbbbbCdAA"));
console.log(...longestUniformSubstring("ab"));
console.log(...longestUniformSubstring("aa"));
console.log(...longestUniformSubstring(""));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of the character being evaluated.  When it changes, check to see if its repetition is larger than previous repetitions.  If so, store the new version and move on.

```js
function longestUniformSubstring(input){
  const result = [-1, 0];
  let currentCharacter = '';
  let currentIndex = -1;
  let currentCount = 0;
  
  (input || '').split('').forEach((character, index) => {
    if (character == currentCharacter) {
      currentCount++;
    } else {
      if (currentCount > result[1]) {
        result[0] = currentIndex;
        result[1] = currentCount;
      }
      
      currentCharacter = character;
      currentIndex = index;
      currentCount = 1;
    }
  });

  if (currentCount > result[1]) {
    result[0] = currentIndex;
    result[1] = currentCount;
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(longestUniformSubstring("abbbccdddda"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write the logic like this, this works at my end.

```js
function longestUniformSubstring(input) {
      let length = input.length;
      let firstLetter = input[0];
      let sIndex = 0;
      let eIndex = 0;
      let resultIndex = 0;
      let resultLength = 0;
    
      while(sIndex < length && eIndex < length) {
         if (input[eIndex] === firstLetter) {     
          eIndex++;
          if (eIndex - sIndex > resultLength) {       
            resultLength = eIndex - sIndex;
            resultIndex = sIndex;
          }
        } 
        else {
          sIndex++;
          if (input[sIndex] !== firstLetter) 
             { 
               firstLetter = input[sIndex]; 
             }
        }
      }
      return [resultIndex, resultLength];
    }
    
 console.log(longestUniformSubstring('AABBBBBCC'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate over

```
function longestUniformSubstring(input){
    if(!input) {
        return [-1, 0];
    }
    let lastIndex=0;
    let lastLength=1;
    let currIndex=0;
    let currLength=0;
    for (let i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
        if(input.charAt(i)===input.charAt(i-1)) {
            currLength++;
        } else {
            if (currLength > lastLength) {
                lastIndex = currIndex;
                lastLength = currLength;
            }
            currIndex = i;
            currLength = 1;
        }
    }
    return [lastIndex, lastLength];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `queue`, to keep track of elements. and pop once all the iteration has been done.

```js
function longestUniformSubstring(input) {
  if (!input) return [-1, 0];
  let queue = [];
  const map = {};
  for (let index = 0; index < input.length; index++) {
    const char = input[index];
    if (!map[char]) map[char] = [index, 1];
    else {
      map[char][1] += 1;
    }
    const max = queue[0];
    if (max && max[1] < map[char][1]) {
      queue.unshift(map[char]);
    } else {
      queue.push(map[char]);
    }
  }
  return queue.shift();
}
console.log(longestUniformSubstring("abbbccda"));
console.log(longestUniformSubstring("10000111"));
console.log(longestUniformSubstring("aabbbbbCdAA"));
```

The dirty one, keep track of longest

```js
function longestUniformSubstring(input) {
  if (!input) return [-1, 0];
  let max = ["", -1, 0];
  let map = {}
  for (let index = 0; index < input.length; index++) {
    const char = input[index];
    if (!map[char]) map[char] = [index, 1];
    else {
      map[char][1] += 1;
    }
    if (max[2] < map[char][1]) {
      max = [char, map[char][0], map[char][1]];
    }
  }
  return [max[1], max[2]];
}
console.log(longestUniformSubstring("abbbccda"));
console.log(longestUniformSubstring("10000111"));
console.log(longestUniformSubstring("aabbbbbCdAA"));
```

You can use `.reduce` to count. `.sort` method to get the min or max.

```js
function longestUniformSubstring(input) {
  if (!input) return [-1, 0];
  const map = input.split("").reduce((m, item, index) => {
    if (!m[item]) m[item] = [index, 1];
    else {
      m[item][1] += 1;
    }
    return m;
  }, {});
  return Object.values(map).sort(([_, i], [__, j]) => j - i)[0];
}
console.log(longestUniformSubstring("abbbccda"));
console.log(longestUniformSubstring("10000111"));
console.log(longestUniformSubstring("aabbbbbCdAA"));
```